# ERC20 token transfer with a multisignature wallet

Tags: transactions, erc-20, multisignature

I have a multisignature wallet(it is a different contract). I have some tokens to transfer to another address(token is an ERC20 and can transfer via (yourContract.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount)) Multisignature is done by contract similar to (https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/MultiSigWalletWithDailyLimit.sol). Can anyone help how to transfer token(Not ether) ?

Comment: It depends on the code of multisignature contract. If it has the same ABI as `MultiSigWalletWithDailyLimit.sol` you should be able to use https://wallet.gnosis.pm